# How do I parse a CSV list enclosed in brackets in Python?

Tags: python, string, text, csv

I'd like to parse the following raw string into an array:

```
(65.312321,89.314213214214)
```

Being Python, I'd bet there is a beautiful way to do this, I just don't know it!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `>>> p = list(eval('(65.312321,89.314213214214)'))
>>> p[0]
65.312321
>>> p[1]
89.314213214214` but you should read about eval before using!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's syntactically equivalent to python's tuple of floats, you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> print ast.literal_eval("(65.312321,89.314213214214)")
(65.312321, 89.314213214214)
```

If you want, you can convert it to a list:

```
>>> print list(ast.literal_eval("(65.312321,89.314213214214)"))
[65.312321, 89.314213214214]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python you do not have array's. You either end up having data in an immutable tuple or a mutable List. Your best bet is to use ast for this purpose

```
>>> import ast
>>> st = "(65.312321,89.314213214214)"
>>> ast.literal_eval(st) # as a tuple
(65.312321, 89.314213214214)
>>> list(ast.literal_eval(st)) # as a list
[65.312321, 89.314213214214]
```

You may if you desire can also strip out the parenthesis and split by comma

```
>>> st.strip("() ").split(",")
['65.312321', '89.314213214214']
```